# How to build a calculator with dropdown fields that have different variables assigned to values

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to build a "required xp" calculator for a game I play, within the game there are many skills that are grouped into classes. Each of the skills requires a different amount of xp to level up. I have already got the xp data needed to build the tool, and although I am pretty confident with Html and Css, I am a total beginner with PHP.

I want to build a form that has three dropdowns:

1. skill type (values:adventuring|crafting)
   This dropdown should limit the second dropdowns displayed values to the relevant skill groups)
2. skill group (values:fire magic|blades|archery|healing etc etc etc)
   This dropdown should limit the third dropdowns displayed values to the relevant skills within the chosen group)

3  individual skill (coupe de grace,slash,rapid fire etc etc etc)
The value selected here would select the relevant one of nine XP arrays, eg:

```
$xpreq = array('1' => '0',
             '2' => '105',
             '3' => '116',
            '4' => '128');

$xpreq['1'] = '0';
$xpreq['2'] = '105';
$xpreq['3'] = '116';
$xpreq['4'] = '128';
```

Underneath the three dropdown fields, there would be another two text fields, where the user can input their current skill level and their desired skill level (1-200). The tool would then return how much xp the player needed to get from their current skill level to their desired skill level. So if the player entered "2 as there current level and "4" the tool would deduct $xpreq['2'] from $xpreq['4'] and display the value of 23.

I realise this is a big ask given the complexity of the task and my almost non-existent php knowledge, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplished the dropdown effect that you want, first you need to store the data into database, or since the data is static, store into a JSON file.

Then, use Javascript or jQuery to do Ajax call to the database/file each time a drop box is selected.
As example, when drop down 1 is selected, the ajax call will fired and fetch the data based on the drop down 1 value, after that appends the fetched data to drop down 2. And so on to the other drop down.

Read: http://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/